# localGroovy method within plugin groovy code

Tags: gradle

In my plugins, I am always trying to add Groovy to Java. Now this code works just fine when in a `build.gradle` file, but when I move it to a plugin groovy file so I can compile it and distribute it, it says it can't find the method `localGroovy()`.  What's the correct syntax to call the `localGroovy()` method here?

```
project.with {
    plugins.withType(JavaPlugin) {
        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force localGroovy()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `localGroovy()` is defined in the [`DependencyHandler`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html) interface. I don't know where in your build script you were using the above code snippet, but you would need to be in the scope of a `DependencyHandler` to access this method. However, in your plugin, you could just use the `DependencyHandler` under `projects.dependencies`:

```
[...]
resolutionStrategy {
    force project.dependencies.localGroovy()
}
[...]
```

Please note, that I did not test this code and it relies on your statement that the used method `force(...)` can handle whatever [`Dependency`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Dependency.html) implementation is returned by `localGroovy()`.

According to [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:force(java.lang.Object[])), the `force(...)` method can handle the following inputs:

> - String in a format of: `'group:name:version'`, for example: `'org.gradle:gradle-core:1.0'`
> - instance of [`ModuleVersionSelector`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleVersionSelector.html)
> - any collection or array of above will be automatically flattened

As long as the `Dependency` returned by `localGroovy()` implements the `ModuleVersionsSelector` interface (e.g. as [`ExternalDependency`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ExternalDependency.html)), the solution above should work like a charm.

Comment: i tried that before, it comes back with invalid format.

Comment: Could you try to add brackets around the argument of the `force()` method?